# CoreNLP: English_SD model last update time

Tags: stanford-nlp

> Since version 3.5.2 the Stanford Parser and Stanford CoreNLP output grammatical relations in the Universal Dependencies v1 representation by default.

I wonder if Stanford still improving the `English_SD` parser model or it's concentrated on improving `English_UD` instead. What was the last time `English_SD` got updated?

[Mailing list archive](https://mailman.stanford.edu/pipermail/java-nlp-announce/2017-January.txt) tells me there are `new neural dependency parsing models for English` released in 3.7.0, but I'm not sure if it's SD and/or UD models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are not updating SD any more, that description is a reference to a new UD model.